# Double linked list print

Tags: python, linked-list

In my task I need to put char into a double linked list and print them.

I initialized Node and DLL(+ append):

```
class Node:
    def __init__ (self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None
        self.prev = None

class DoublyLinkedList():
    def __init__(self):
        self.head =None

    def append(self, data):
        if self.head is None:
            new_node = Node(data)
            new_node.prev = None
            self.head = new_node
        else:
            new_node = Node(data)
            cur = self.head
            while cur.next:
                cur = cur.next
            cur.next =new_node
            new_node.prev = cur
            new_node.next = None
```

Then I have to make function for printing and function to put char into a DDL:

```
def print(self):

current = self.head
if (self.head == None):
    print ("List is empty")
    return

while(current != None):
    print(current.data)
    current = current.next
        
def Lista(lista):
    doubleLinked = DoublyLinkedList()
    for element in lista:
        doubleLinked.append(element)
```

This is how I call these functions. This part I cannot change!

```
L = Lista(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']) 
print(L)
```

I got this error:

```
<ipython-input-5-1c60a61c4137> in print(self)
     33 def print(self):
     34 
---> 35     current = self.head
     36     if (self.head == None):
     37         print ("List is empty")

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'head'
```

Comment: What do you mean with [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DDL)? Also, you have an indentation problem in the second code block.

Comment: For me DDL is double linked list, but I saw it's data definition language. I will edit it.

Comment: Then don't you mean DLL? What is the second D about?

Comment: Yes, it is DLL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In function Lista you have to return your doubleLinked list.